# When we load our libraries(business logic) into the spring boot framework then the application is getting overloaded?

Tags: spring, spring-boot

We are going to developing a web application using the Spring boot framework. Now, we are an architect for how to build a system. Our team members asked questions like when we load our libraries into the spring boot framework then the application is getting overloaded?

Please help me. Is the application is overloaded or not?

Comment: what do you mean by framework overloading?

Comment: it still doesn't make sense

Comment: @LakshmananRengasamy can you give an example ?

Comment: you can add as many libraries in your app as you want. it's a common practice. An app without third party libs it is a very simple app commonly

Comment: Thanks. I can understand.